# Pitch class profile, chromagram

Tags: audio, pitch

Is it possible to create your own Pitch Class Profile (PCP) of given notes? I want to create possible candidates which I will be comparing with wav audio.

I know that it is possible to match a chromagram of a chord with audio and thus estimate which chord is played, but this chromagram is given in advance.

For example, I expected: F4 C5 D5, and I want to create a PCP which I will compare with a chromagram of played sound.

Comment: I found this question quite late, admittedly - but there is a digital signal processing site on the Stack Exchange network that might give you a better pool of potential answers. http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm certainly no expert, but wouldn't it be easier to extract the most dominant frequencies in a Pitch Class Profile and compare them to something like an array of your expected notes? They could even be in string format as long as your function extracted notes by name from the incoming chromagram.